# Itchy Offtopic Trigger

Tags: discussion, support

I asked the following question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6178288/online-computer-science-bs-degree, which was closed in minutes as being off-topic.

How does Computer Science not have to do with software development. Are computer science degrees not "matters that are unique to the programming profession"?

Answer (score 15):

> Does anyone know of a good online undergraduate **[X]** program? My girlfriend is almost done her Masters of Science in Nursing online at Vanderbilt. All her courses are online, she does clinicals at local hospitals and private practices, and flies to Nashville for a long weekend every couple of months. I've been looking for something similar for **[X]**, but can only seem to find programs at scam schools. If it's possible to get the credentials which will give you the ability to suture and prescribe narcotics online, shouldn't **[X]** be handled similarly?
>
> Yes, I am aware of the social implications (e.g. college is a great place to meet people, develop as a person, etc...). I did attend a traditional college, and have about 85 credits. The difficulty is, my business started making money, so I'm too busy to attend scheduled courses. The university wouldn't work with me, at all, so I stopped going. I see value in having a degree, and would like to finish, but it has to be on my time.

How is that unique to programming again?

Comment: What are you going to do with a computer science degree that isn't programming or computer science research?

Comment: @jcnnghm balpha's point is that your question is not *unique* to programming.  You could be asking about a physics degree and the answers would be exactly the same.

Comment: @Adam Davis - The degree granting programs for physics and computer science are exactly the same at every school?  We know computer science and MSN programs aren't the same at every school.  If they were, Vanderbilt would be offering a comparable computer science program, wouldn't they? Is the answer to the question, how do I make a program that prints text on the screen the same in every language?  Is this difference important or notable?  Context does matter here.

Comment: The answer to your question is not going to solve anybody's programming problem (including yours). Hence it is off-topic for SO.

Comment: @Jcnnghm It doesn't matter if the question only applies to programmers or not.  What matters if it solves a programming problem, not a programmer's problem. You're question is a problem a programmer might have, but it's not a programming problem.  You may not agree that the difference should matter, but I hope you can at least understand the difference between a programmer's problem and a programming problem, and accept that this site does not permit programmer's problems except those which are also programming problems.

Comment: @Adam Davis - That actually makes sense.  The FAQ should be revised to say exactly that.  Any mention of "the programming profession" should be removed, since it's clear that nothing about the programming profession is on topic.

Answer (score 11):

You question is about *programmers* (as in where should they go to school) rather than *programming*, so if it has a place at all it is on [Programmers.SE](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/).{*}

Note that I am not active on that site and wouldn't care to guess if it is on topic there. It is somewhat subjective and may not pass the [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) criteria.

---

{*} Take note of the subjunctive mood here. There is no guarantee that every question has a place in the Stack Exchange network. If you feel that a question that dosen't currently have a place *should* have one, you can try [Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: So why isn't the topic moved then?

Comment: If the closers were *also* unsure of it's appropriateness on Programmers they may have preferred a simple close to the possibility of an unwanted migration. Or perhaps they *were* sure that it would not be well received.